# VIm copy & paste between apps as a non-superuser

Tags: linux, vim

I'm using a work computer so i don't have a root access. 
I've tried "+y, "*y, set clipboard=unnamed. It looks like my vim doesn't support +clipboard (version 7.0).
I'm using Linux Centos 5 so fakeclips doesn't actually help (i think)

Please help. It's a pain to type stuff manually from firefox to vim or other apps and vice versa.

Comment: Just to make sure, vim -> firefox using `"+y` and then `Ctrl-V` doesn't work. Neither does firefox -> vim using `Ctrl-C` and then `"+gP` ?

Answer (score 3):

Often times Linux distributions include a `vim` that does not support X11 or the clipboard. If you have `gvim` installed, you can run `gvim` in text mode by running it as

```
gvim -v
```

Try that and see if that fixes the problem. If it does, and if you don't want to type `gvim -v` all the time, you can create an alias,

```
alias vim='gvim -v'
```

or a link, e.g.,

```
ln -s $(which gvim) ~/bin/vim
```

For that, you'll need your own ~/bin directory and that directory early in your PATH, e.g., by putting

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

in your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile if ~/bin is not already in your PATH.

Comment: Sometimes distributions include a /bin/vi, which is a stripped down version of Vim, and then optionally /usr/bin/vim and /usr/bin/gvim, which can have various feature sets enabled depending on the distributor.  Often people are invoking Vim as "vi" when they should be typing "vim'.

Answer (score 0):

I second the motion to install `gvim` (and use it).

You may have the `DISPLAY` variable unset. Fix it by (usually, on the primary X vt:)

```
export DISPLAY=:0
gvim
```

If all else fails you may find a workaround in `xclip`

```
:'<,'>w !xclip
:w !xclip -selection clipboard
```

Answer (score 0):

I've given up on vim for that. Now i'm using gvim. i guess that's the only solution. 
Thanks guys